# How to model variations in OpenAPI specification?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have datatypes in my OpenAPI schema like this (simplified):

```yaml
member:
   title: member
   required:
       - id
       - name
       - bookings
   type: object
   properties:
       id:
           type: string
           description: 'Unique Id of record'
       name:
           description: Clear Text name
           type: string
    /* Many more properties here */
       bookings:
           description: all booking ids
           type: array
           items:
               type: string
   additionalProperties: false

fullMember:
   title: member with bookings resolved
   required:
       - id
       - name
       - bookings
   type: object
   properties:
       id:
           type: string
           description: 'Unique Id of record'
       name:
           description: Clear Text name
           type: string
    /* Many more properties here */
       bookings:
           description: all booking ids
           type: array
           items:
               $ref: '#/components/schemas/bookings'
   additionalProperties: false

newMember:
   title: member creation object
   required:
       - name
   type: object
   properties:
       /* id is system generated, must not submit */
       name:
           description: Clear Text name
           type: string
    /* Many more properties here */
       bookings:
           description: all booking ids
           type: array
           items:
               $ref: '#/components/schemas/bookings'
   additionalProperties: false
```

They are all variations of each other: new submission (no id), return (with id), complete (bookings resolved). The challenge is the part with `/* Many more properties here */` which need to keep in sync over the variations. My first thought was to introduce a `details` element:

```yaml
newMember:
   title: member creation object
   required:
       - details
   type: object
   properties:
       details:
           description: member details
           $ref: '#/components/schemas/memberdetails'
       /* id is system generated, must not submit */
       bookings:
           description: all booking ids
           type: array
           items:
               $ref: '#/components/schemas/bookings'
   additionalProperties: false
```

But this adds a nested property in JSON, I'd rather keep them on one level.

Is there a way to share groups of properties across schemas?

Comment: ahh thank you for the downvote without a comment #troll